# Is there a standard for transparency of objects?

Tags: optics, visible-light

Im in the process of building a luminosity measurement device just as a project. I was trying to pick a material to enclose the sensor and LDRs in while trying to chose a material I couldn’t find a standardized study that quantifies how much light at each spectrum a material allows it to pass, is there a theoretical way this can be done without setting up an experiment and seeing how much light is absorbed compared to no enclosure and so on..

Comment: What do you mean by "standardized study"? You can find absorption spectra for various materials.

Comment: It occurs to me that "transparency" is a poorly defined concept. This may explain why there is no standard metric such as you seek. Perhaps you're looking for light conductivity? Any sufficiently thin "opaque" material will appear transparent and any sufficiently thick "transparent" material will appear opaque. Relatively thick (a few mm) glass appears transparent because the direction of light "passing through" it is preserved, but as i understand it glass does absorb and emit visible light. It doesn't simply "pass through" unhindered which is why the speed of light through glass is slower.

Comment: There are some tries to predict the reflectivity from first principles : check [Predicting the reflectivity and colour of metals from first principles](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/211997989.pdf) and [Matrix method to predict the spectral reflectance of stratified surfaces including thick layers and thin films](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279259490_Matrix_method_to_predict_the_spectral_reflectance_of_stratified_surfaces_including_thick_layers_and_thin_films). Yes, it's non-trivial task, because you need to evaluate electronic structure which for composite materials can be hard.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I was wondering. Forexample for the coefficient of static friction between two materials, there is a table that is fairly consistent as long as the materials and environment are the same. Is there a similar thing for how much light passes through specific mediums as a function of their thickness or just any thing like that.